# Scanning for malware in files uploaded to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am building a .net app (Azure app service) with file upload feature that would upload pdf/docx files to Azure blob storage.

I was just wondering if a malicious user uploads a virus infected file, bad macro in word file, is Azure able to scan and remove/quarantine that file?

In the app, admin user will be able to download the file using a url. Will that file be virus free? Or do I need to explicitly call antivirus like Symantec End Point after the admin downloads the file.

Please let me know your expert thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, there's no solution for that available on Azure. You'd need to use 3rd party or build one yourself. In the future, you'll be able to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/threat-protection

Comment: Looks like Azure ATP is now available for Azure Blob Storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/threat-protection#azure-storage

Comment: Indeed. It's worths to mention there's no API where you can "force" a scan, it can take up to 2 hours to scan your blob too.

Comment: I've been going very deep on this subject lately. **Findings:** ATP scans only produce output when an Alert is triggered. There is no way to hook into a "no malware found" message in ATP. There is an ATP Alert [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/alerts/listbyresourcegroup), but again, it only hosts Alerts when a malware signature has been found. Thus you would have to rely on a timer essentially (if no ATP Alerts found after polling the REST API for 10hrs(?), then deem the file "safe"). This doesn't fit the bill for deterministic scanning.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Azure Advanced Threat Protection [is now available for Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/threat-protection#azure-storage) (and other Azure resources).

Comment: It's worths to mention there's no API where you can "force" a scan, it can take up to 2 hours to scan your blob too.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source solution that my team implemented, Its a small antivirus system that sends all uploaded blobs from a specific container to antivirus scan (using VM with Microsoft defender) and the blob is moved based on the scan results to a different container.
Also the remediation can be modified.

You can use that solution to send to scan each blob uploaded and download blobs only from a "clean-container".

here's a link to the repo [azure-storage-av-automation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-av-automation).

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this repo can answer and add partial code/... about how to use ?

Comment: Edited my comment. The usage is detailed in the Readme file.